# Uncountable subset of separable metric space that does not contain a convergent sequence of points

Tags: general-topology

Does there exist a separable metric space with an uncountable subset which does not contain a convergent sequence of distinct points?

Comment: Consider the discrete metric on any uncountable set. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_space

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich That space is not separable.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich an uncountable set with the discrete metric would not be separable

Comment: Sorry, missed the word separable...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. A separable metric space $X$ is hereditarily Lindelöf (even second countable). And this implies that every uncountable subset $A$ of $X$ has a point $p$ such that every ball around $p$ intersects $A$ in uncountably many points (otherwise every point is locally countable and we use the Lindelöfness of $A$ to get a contradiction). And this allows us to get a lot of convergent sequences to $p$.

Alternatively show that a set without convergent sequences is discrete in itself (in a metric space) and use the fact that every subset of a separable metric space is separable too.